# How can i have line numbers in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to enable show line numbers in android studio. But I couldn't find it. How can I enable show line numbers in Android Studio?

Comment: You can always Ctrl+Shift+A and just type whatever you're looking for. More often than not, it will find the right thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > show line numbers

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
You can enable the line number from this    
File Menu > Settings > expand Editor > Appearance
```

Answer (score 5):

Right click on sideline of your coding area.

[image]

or

File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > show line numbers

Answer (score 2):

File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > show line numbers

Answer (score 2):

Though editor

Right click on sideline of your coding area.

```
>> select show line numbers
```

Through settings

> File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > show line numbers

Answer (score 1):

### How To Show line numbers In Android Studio

> File > Settings > Editor > Appearance then click the "Show line
>   numbers" box.

For more information Please read [Android Studio Tips and Tricks](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html)

Answer (score 1):

I am using Android Studio 2.1.1. I think there is an easy way to do this. At the top left of your editor there is a `View` menu drop down. 
Go to `View > Active Editor`.
Then enable the `Show Line Numbers`. It will show the line numbers.